# How to position WebView below TextView in layout and center horizontal?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to position WebView below TextView in layout and center horizontal ? Idea is at first row be button, textView, button and in second row webview.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
        style="@style/question_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPreviousQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_arrow_left"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNextQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_arrow_right"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </Button>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvMultimediaQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: FrameLayout Stacks up elements one on top of each other started from top left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead of a FrameLayout. Using a RelativeLayout you can define the position of views within the layout relatively to each other.

For example the attribute android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtQuestion" on the second button would assure that the second button is to the right of the text view. The RelativeLayout several of those [attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) you can use to define your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
        style="@style/question_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
      />
    <Button
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtQuestion"
        android:id="@+id/btnPreviousQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_arrow_left"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout`.. it will be quite loadz easy that way. :)